# Conditional inside for loop or lots of for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make my code work differently for different values of i in for loop, but I don't know if I should make the conditional go inside the loop or just create multiple for loops for enhanced speed.

My English does seem quite inefficient at explaining things, so here's an example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
    if (i < 11) {
        System.out.println(3*i);
    } else if (i<21) {
        System.out.println(2*i);
    } else System.out.println(i);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) System.out.println(3*i);
for (int i = 11; i < 21; i++) System.out.println(2*i);
for (int i = 21; i < 31; i++) System.out.println(i);
```

It would really help if the reason why one of them might be better or not could be explained as well. Thank you in advance :>

Comment: Run each version a million times, and time it.

Comment: And really, don't care about performance or "enhanced speed" the first (or second, or third etc.) thing you do. Instead concentrate on writing good, readable and *maintainable* code, and that it works. Then if it's not good enough (and good enough usually *is* good enough) or you have certain performance requirements, then you measure and benchmark and profile the code to find the worst bottlenecks and fix them (with documentation, comments and unit-testing).

Answer (score 3):

Enhanced speed should not be a consideration. The differences (if any) would be negligible.

You should choose the more readable version. When using a `for` loop, you usually mean you wish to perform the same action `N` times. In your case you want to perform 3 different actions, each a different number of times (or for different values of `i`). Therefore it makes more sense to have 3 loops.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    System.out.println(3*i);
}
for (int i = 11; i < 21; i++) {
    System.out.println(2*i);
}
for (int i = 21; i < 31; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: I guess the difference would be probably a thousandth of a millisecond or something like that. Just out of curiosity. Thank you anyways! Would keep in mind about the readability.

Comment: @eran by looking at the comparisons.
The single loop will loop have more comparisons.Hence it indirectly effect the performance

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra If doesn't make sense to discuss performance of a loop having 30 iterations. And even if we were talking about millions of iterations, I doubt the time difference would be meaningful.

Comment: Whilst i agree that you should use multiple loops, i don't agree with the reasoning. You should use multiple loops because you negate branching entirely which has an adverse effect on the performance (albeit minimal in this case). The bottom line is, for an operation like this, it really doesn't matter. As for readability, both are absolutely fine, no dev worth their salt would question you on either solution.

Answer (score 2):

The first single loop analysis :-
 Number of variable initialized 1.
 Number of comparisons :-

1. 1 < 31
2. 1 < 11
3. 2 < 31
4. 2 < 11
   so on.

Hence for 1 to 10 number of comparison 20.

for 11 to 20 number of comparison 30.
for 21 to 30 number of comparison 30.

so total **80 comparison for single loop**.
but

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) System.out.println(3*i);
for (int i = 11; i < 21; i++) System.out.println(2*i);
for (int i = 21; i < 31; i++) System.out.println(i);
```

total comparison 31.

So the seperate loop is good instead of if else ledder.

Answer (score 1):

Make the code readable is more important. The performance difference is very small, which can be ignored in most cases. Here is the experement result on my computer:

pattern 1:

- run 100000 times cost 7548 milli seconds
- run 1000000 times cost 70180 milli seconds

pattern 2:

- run 100000 times cost 7536 milli seconds
- run 1000000 times cost 70535 milli seconds

Answer (score 0):

Unless driven by performance considerations let readability lead you.
The second one is surely easier to understand. Though I'd recommend using block statements:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    System.out.println(3*i);
}
for (int i = 11; i < 21; i++) {
    System.out.println(2*i);
}
for (int i = 21; i < 31; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Of course you could make a formula:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
    int fac=3-((i-1)/10);
    System.out.println(fac*i);
}
```

Though that seems fairly unreadable too it might be the best approach if the equivalent were many `for`-loops or a number of loops you couldn't determine at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 for loops are faster (not important here), as there no longer is an if-else-if at every i-step. More important the three loops are far more readable because the if cascade is removed.

However using `j = i + 1` the first loop can be converted to:

```
final int n = 30;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    int k = n/10 - j/10;
    System.out.println(k * (j + 1));
}
```

Because of the division this will probably not be faster. However the removal of the if-cascade is an improvement. The expressions are harder to interprete while reading, but they specify a bit of calculating logic, which the mere stating of if conditions would not: *one could change 30 with 300 and still everything would make sense.*

Or

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    for (int i = 1 + j*10; i < 11 + j*10; i++) {
        System.out.println((3-j)*i);
    }
}
```